# How can I apply a jQuery function to all elements with the same class.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JQuery return value for all same name class = `2.53` (first element value applied for all Span)

How do I get different values?

(Edit:) HTML code:

```
<div class='ratingInfo'>
    <table class='rating_table' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
             <div class='review-rating'>10</div>
          </td>
          <td>
             <div class='stars1'></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<div class='ratingInfo'>
    <table class='rating_table' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <div class='review-rating'>1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='stars1'></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

JavaScript

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".stars1" ).html("<span class='stars'>"+$('.review-rating').text()+"</span>");
    $('span.stars').stars();
 });

 $.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5,   parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
    });
 }
```

Comment: P.S. In your `$.fn.stars` function `this` is *already* a jQuery object.  You can just do `return this.each(function(){ //... });`.

Comment: That wasn't a *solution* to the problem, I was just pointing it out.

Comment: Working fine with out table why is that.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `$('.review-rating').text()` is grabbing the first element every time, it does not know you want the one that is beside the element. You need to code it to look there.

```
$( ".stars1" ).each( function () {
    var star = $(this);
    star.html("<span class='stars'>" + star.prev('.review-rating').text() + "</span>");
});
```

with the new HTML code, the above will not work since the elements are NOT siblings. That is why it is important to have the actual code! You need to look for a common parent and find the element within it, in this case you have the TR that contains both. So to get the parent, use closest()

```
$( ".stars1" ).each( function () {
    var star = $(this);
    var rating = star.closest("tr").find(".review-rating").text();
    star.html("<span class='stars'>" + rating + "</span>");
});
```

Comment: thanks for quick solution but didn't return any value on span . those are empty. Tried At javaScript demo It's working perfect but not in my page.?

Comment: OF course it would not work with that HTML because the element is not a sibling....