# Apply function to all items in an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, wildcard

I have a list of ids that I have created with a foreach loop. I'm using a jquery script to change the value of a dropdown box based on the value of another dropdown box. I'm trying to change the script so that it will apply to all of the items instead of each individually.

I've tried a for loop and various wildcards - I feel like it should be really easy but I just can't make it work.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#changeall").change(function() {
    $("#item1").val($(this).val());
    $("#item2").val($(this).val());
    $("#item3").val($(this).val());
  });
});
</script>
```

This works but it just want it to apply to #item* so that I don't have to list them all.

Many thanks.

Per request, the accompanying dropdowns:

```
<?php 
$ii = 1;
foreach ($trails as $trail): ?>
            <h4><?= htmlspecialchars(trail->getAttribute("name")) ?></h4>
              <select name="trailstatusform[]" id="item<?= htmlspecialchars($ii) ?>" class="bww">
                <option selected value="<?= htmlspecialchars($trail->getAttribute("status")) ?>">
                  <?= htmlspecialchars($trail->getAttribute("status")) ?>
                </option>
                <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
                <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
              </select>
<?php 
$ii++;
endforeach; ?>   

<select id="changeall">
  <option value=" "> </option>
  <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Also played with .each - would you be so kind as to provide me an example of how this might work with my code as I'm fairly new to this? I added a class instead of id but it's still not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply a jQuery function to all elements with the same class.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026025/how-can-i-apply-a-jquery-function-to-all-elements-with-the-same-class)

Comment: Perhaps, but I still don't know how to apply it in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` and either a wildcard selector (`^=`) on the `id` attribute, or use a `class` attribute selection:

```js
$('#changeall').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("[id^=item]").each(function() { 
        $(this).val(value);
    });
    // or, class-based (this is the preferred way)
    $("select.bww").each(function() { 
        $(this).val(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>Items:<br>
<select name="trailstatusform[]" id="item1" class="bww">
    <option selected value="status">status</option>
    <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
    <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
</select><p>
<select name="trailstatusform[]" id="item2" class="bww">
    <option selected value="status">status</option>
    <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
    <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
</select>
<hr>

<br>Change all:<br> 
<select id="changeall">
  <option value=" "> </option>
  <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tried this and also with class but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It works for me, but I have to guess what your HTML is like. Could you add it to your question so we know exactly what your referenced elements are?

Comment: Are `item1`, `item2` ... `select` elements?

Comment: Yes, the items are select elements. I added the referenced elements to the question.

Comment: I have added a runnable snippet to my answer: it works fine. Could you change your question's HTML to plain HTML, as how it looks in the browser (so no PHP)? That way there is no doubt about the actual HTML that jQuery works with.

Comment: Hmm, I can see that your code snippet works but even when I drop it into an html file all by it's lonesome it still doesn't do anything and there are no errors...

Comment: Nevermind, I needed to run the code after the select. It works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So use the class that is common on each of them and set the value.

```js
$("#changeall").on("change", function(){
   $(".bww").val(this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="bww">
  <option value=" "> </option>
  <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
</select>

<select class="bww">
  <option value=" "> </option>
  <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
</select>

<select class="bww">
  <option value=" "> </option>
  <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
</select>

<hr/>

<select id="changeall">
  <option value=" "> </option>
  <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There is no need to do the each like in the other answer. jQuery does it for you....